# Amazon S3 - List ALL objects without hierarchy summaries

Tags: java, amazon-s3

For what it's worth, the Amazon S3 library is being used to perform operations on HCP. Perhaps that limits the version of Amazon S3 we can use or changes the interpretation of a folder. My understanding is, both Amazon S3 and HCP can acknowledge full paths as objects and ignore the folders, but I'm having difficulty getting my requests to do just that.

Say I have:

- something/over/here/object1
- something/over/there/object2
- somewhere/far/object3

and I want every object under something/. Here is my request attempt:

```
ListObjectsRequest listSomeObjects= new ListObjectsRequest()
.withBucketName("bucket")
.withDelimiter("/")
.withPrefix("something/")
.withMaxKeys("100") // maybe not necessary since it stops at 1000
.withMarker(null); // to be used after first request, I imagine
ObjectListing objectsReturned = this.hs3Client.listObjects(listSomeObjects);
```

objectsReturned gives me a few options:

- getCommonPrefixes() - if I include a delimiter, returns something/over. Otherwise, appears to be empty.
- getObjectSummaries() - With the delimiter, only returns objects immediately under something/ and itself. In this case, it only has itself. Without the delimiter, returns a list of object summaries for something/, something/over/, something/over/here, something/over/there/, something/over/here/object1, something/over/there/object2.
- getBucketName(), getMarker(), getMaxKeys(), getDelimiter(), getNextMarker(), getPrefix() - these don't appear to be anything I need

I only need a list of the full object names: something/over/here/object1, something/over/there/object2

Looping through all of getObjectSummaries() to filter the results would be a last resort. Using an incredible amount of small requests to account for the subfolders  may not even be viable for our use case. Is there a way to get a list of full object names with a common prefix without going through all the keys in getObjectSummaries()?

Answer (score 0):

Which amazon library version are you using?

I can tell you that i've been using

```
AmazonS3.listObjects(String bucketName, String prefix)
```

and i only received the list of existing matching keys. Only actual objects, not the "virtual folder" subpaths (using getObjectSummaries method as you do)

As far as i know that is equivalent to your code but without the delimiter (keeping aside maxkeys).

I used version 1.10.52 just in case it matters (would be surprised).

Comment: It was previously 1.4.1 when created, so I increased it to 1.10.52. I also used that version of the function instead of making the ListObjectsRequest to be consistent, but I'm still getting too many results for getObjectSummaries(). The keys are still "something/","something/over/","something/over/here/" etc

Comment: i know question seems weird, bust just in case: are you sure those keys do not really exist? maybe from a previous test? at the end, you can upload files to any key afaik, even those matching "folder names". i would verify on the aws web console what you see there (i would even try uploading new file to different path through the aws web console to ensure issue is not on the upload through cli).

Answer (score 0):

remove the `.withDelimiter("/")` option would get you all the objects under the prefix

Comment: Without the delimiter, there is nothing returned from getCommonPrefixes (probably to be expected). getObjectSummaries gives me "something/","something/over/","something/over/here/" etc. I need it to only return "something/over/here/object1" and "something/over/there/object2" in this case.

Comment: That's probably because you used a tool that created empty directory blobs for "something/","something/over/","something/over/here/". The API usage is supposed to only return actual objects so it's the expected behavior in this case. You will have to filter on the client side for objects that didn't end in '/'.